# SQL Server 2014 re install error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

When I want to install SQL Server 2014 it shows this kind of error below in image. What should I do?

[SQL Server install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3wqr.jpg)

Comment: Where did you download the setup from? Have you looked at the setup logs. If not, then please have a look at the logs. This [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702(v=sql.120).aspx) might help.

Comment: i think the setup is corrupted?